# Jquery Timing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, load-order

Right now I am appending a handlebars template to a div. I want to use this on the code -

```
test = $(".someClass:onScreen")
```

I know that onScreen works because I've logged that same line when mousing over that class and it returns the stuff on screen. Now, this is happening because I have a slideUp() on the stuff that's in the div that I'm appending to. I know this because when I do a slideDown(), the line returns stuff correctly.

How do I get around this? Is there some event I can listen for when slideUp is finished?

EDIT-

I tried using Jquery slideUps callback as well, still no avail -

```
    @$el.find("#container").slideDown('fast',@appendSearchResults(resultsCollection))
    @$el.find("#container").empty()

  appendSearchResults:(resultsCollection)=>
    @$el.find("#searchContainerId").append(Handlebars.templates["resultsPage"](
      row: resultsCollection.toJSON()
      nResults: resultsCollection.length
      ))
    @genImageToolTip()
    console.log("testing ons creen")
    test = $(".carImageClass:onScreen")
    console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.slideUp()` has an argument for a completion function that will get called when the animation finishes.  Details are fairly clear here in [the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

When passing the callback, it takes a simple function reference, not a function call.  If you put a function call there (with parens after it that make it execute), then that function is executed immediately, not later.  Your code doesn't look like regular javascript so I can't suggest exactly how it should work.  A normal javascript callback would be like this:

```
$("#whatever").slideUp(2000, function() {
   // do whatever you want to do upon completion
});
```

or like this:

```
$("#whatever").slideUp(2000, slideDone);

function slideDone() {
    // do whatever you want to do upon completion of the slideUp event
}
```

In addition, jQuery has no selector for `:onScreen` built in.  There is a plug-in that can provide that selector if you have installed it and are using it as documented.

---

As for your specific code, I don't know CoffeeScript, but I will try to show you some related examples in plain javascript.

You can do this:

```
$el.find("#container").slideDown('fast', function() { 
    appendSearchResults(resultsCollection)
});

function appendSearchResults(resultsCollection) {
    // code here
}
```

You cannot do this:

```
$el.find("#container").slideDown('fast', appendSearchResults(resultsCollection));

function appendSearchResults(resultsCollection) {
    // code here
}
```

This does not work because this calls appendSearchResults immediately and then passes the return result from that function to slideUp which is not a function.  You need to pass a function reference to slideUp that does not take any arguments.

Comment: sorry, quotes got put in wrong when I was typing up the question

Comment: @praks5432 - I updated my answer based on the new information you added to your question.

Comment: yeah, I tried all that, I've used a delay for now...but it's hacky

Comment: @praks5432 - your current code in your question is wrong.  You haven't done it the way I've shown in my answer or it would have worked.  jQuery animation callbacks work if you do them right.  Why are you ignoring the proper way of doing this?

Comment: @praks5432 - not sure what I can tell you.  You asked a question.  I provided an answer.  You apparently choose to ignore it.  If you don't understand it, ask some clarifying questions.  If you don't think it answers your question, please clarify why.

Comment: I'm telling you why - I think I've done what you've suggested and it isn't working. If I haven't(as shown in the code in the question) because I'm just not seeing what you're typing properly then tell me why I'm wrong. If you can't provide a solution better than what I've thought of, then I can't accept your answer -_-

Comment: @praks5432 - I've added one more example to the end of my answer of what you can and cannot do.  You will have to translate that to CoffeeScript.